# How to use mozCameras in a Firefox OS app?

Tags: camera, firefox-os, firefox-developer-tools

I'm trying to implement mozCameras API in my Firefox OS app, but without luck so far. I'm trying to use the API on an Alcatel Pixi 3 (3.5) phone running Firefox OS 2.0, and also various simulators (2.0, 2.2). I've specified the following section in my manifest.webapp file:

```
"permissions": {
  "camera": {
    "description": "Required to handle camera."
  }
},
```

But I have a strange feeling that during development that tag is ignored, and my app simply doesn't get the necessary permissions from Firefox OS. Is it because to develop for a privileged API the device used for development purposes has to be rooted? And it fails to work in the Firefox OS simulator because the simulator doesn't support mozCameras API? Can we expect a fix for these issues in Firefox OS 2.5?

Answer (score 0):

you can follow the bug [here](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=995483) .Presently no one is working on it but this may be expected soon.